# How to display date format in php?

Tags: php

```
$departure_date = $row['arrival_date'] * $row["numberofnights"];
```

How would I display $departure_date in date format? As currently, arrival_date is in date format and number of nights is a numeric number.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for dates?

Comment: What will you get, when you multiply `2015-01-22` by 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` class for that.

```
$date = new DateTime($row['arrival_date']);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $row["numberofnights"] . 'D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

It'll create new `DateTime` object and add given number of days to it.